# onclick and jQuery event binding causing pain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a link which has an `onclick` attribute, and there is a toggle event that I bind to the link (I know I'm committing a sin here by mixing these two, but there is nothing I can do about it.)

Now to this background, I have 2 scenarios:

1. *The user clicks on the link* - The order of execution of events is :- `onclick` first, then the toggle event bound via jQuery
2. *Fire the `click` event via jQuery* - The order of execution here is different, the bound event fires first then the `onclick`.

Something goes horribly wrong because of these 2 scenarios and the flipping of the order. I need the bound events to run first before the `onclick`. Is there any better way to do this than removing the `onclick` attribute on init and saving them to the link via `.data()` and then handling through the toggle event?

Another thing that I need to take care of (life is complicated), the link can be toggled through the querystring. i.e. if the user comes in from another page via another link, there will be a querystring parameter with the link id, which is read by another JavaScript function that does scenario 2 mentioned above.

So if the `onclick` is to be removed, it will have to be done on init.

What can I do to untangle this mess?

Comment: Post some of your code to get better idea of what r u doing.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is so wrong to remove the `.onclick` function and re-bind it afterwards (after you bound all your methods which should fire before) ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo" onclick="inline();">click me</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function inline() {
    alert('I was bound through onclick=');
}

$(function() {
    var $foo = $('#foo'),
        stored = $foo[0].onclick;

    $foo[0].onclick = null;

    $foo.bind('click', function() {
        alert('I was bound via jQuery');
    });
    $foo.bind('click', stored);
});
```

---

After that code, the order of alerts would be:

```
'I was bound via jQuery'
'I was bound through onclick='
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/3MKWR/

Comment: Yup, this gives me some ideas to tackle my own problem. Thanks!